# Lodash creat object with given keys

Tags: lodash

Let's assume I have following array of strings that represent keys in object.

```
['keyA', 'keyB', 'keyC']
```

I want transform it to following

```
{ keyA: null, keyB: null, keyC: null }
```

Is it possible? I found methods like _.fromPairs etc... but not sure how to transform it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#invert`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#invert) to convert each array values as keys in an object and then use [`lodash#mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues) with [`lodash#constant`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#constant) to set each key with a `null` value.

```
var result = _(data).invert().mapValues(_.constant(null)).value();
```

```js
var data = ['keyA', 'keyB', 'keyC'];

var result = _(data).invert().mapValues(_.constant(null)).value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```